# Close #1 - Forced to Use Inelegant Code. Why?

Tags: vba, input, output

I would love some direction on this...

I would like to use this code:

```
Do While x <> y

    Open myFile.txt For Input As #1
    Open anotherFile.txt For Output As #2

        'doStuff

    Write #2, myString
    Close #1
    Close #2

    Open anotherFile.txt For Input As #3    'Note: same file as #2 above

        'do stuff
    print #3, myString   
    Close #3

Loop
```

The code above occasionally throws : "Run time error 52. Bad file name of number." when attempting to open #3

Yet, upon simply hitting resume it continues with no intervention

What I have to use is this:

```
Do While x <> y

    Open myFile.txt For Input As #1
    Open anotherFile.txt For Output As #2

        'doStuff

    Write #2, myString
    Close #1
    Close #2

    On Error Resume Next
        Close #3             'YES, CLOSE AGAIN
        Sleep 250           'GIVE IT TIME TO ACTUALL CLOSE

        'ATTEMPT TO OPEN  NOTE, SAME FILE AS #2 ABOVE
        Open anotherFile.txt For Input As #3
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then   'CHECK FOR THE ERROR
            Close #3   'ISSUE ANOTHER CLOSE
            Err.Number = 0
            Sleep 250  'GIVE IT SOME TIME AGAIN
            Open anotherFile.txt For Input As #3 'ATTEMPT TO OPEN AGAIN
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then  'ERROR CHECK AGAIN
                MsgBox "Repeated Error " & Err.Description
                Stop
            End If
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

        'do stuff
    Print #3, myString
    Close #3

Loop
```

Fortunately, it never gets past the repeated error checking.  That being said though, I don't like having to use such sloppy code.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks so much!

Trip

Comment: Can you not combine the statements for `#2` and `#3`? (obviously it's overlapping the opening of `anotherFile.txt` before closing it previously, but closing it and then reopening it immediately is not very efficient)

Comment: If you can use FileSystemObject, you code will be neater

Comment: Ahhh, Paul, I just realized why I didn't fully understand your question.  The first open is to write (Output)... the second should have shown that it is for Input.  I'll change it above.  Thank you!

Comment: (1) you're not showing your complete code so it's not possible to see where the error is coming from; (2) you don't "have to" use the sloppy code you posted: there are surely better solutions and someone can help you if you post a complete sample; (3) look at using `FreeFile` rather than hardwired file numbers, but do make sure that the file is always closed, even if an error is raised.

Comment: @TripIves (<-this is how I make sure you get notified of my message). I like questions seeking efficiencies, but you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I remember having a similar issue where I was forced to delay opening of multiple files and it was a bit frustrating so I understand how you feel, but in your case I think there is another issue - I'll provide a more detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues with your code:

1. Assuming `file ID` **`#3`** is available

> [**`FreeFile`** `Function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/freefile-function)
>
> - Returns an Integer representing the next file number available for use by the Open statement
> - File Number - Number used in the Open statement to open a file. Use file numbers in the range 1-255, inclusive, for files not accessible to other applications. Use file numbers in the range 256-511 for files accessible from other applications
>
> **`Syntax`**
>
> - `FreeFile[(rangenumber)]`
>
>   - The optional rangenumber argument is a Variant that specifies the range from which the next free file number is to be returned.
>
>     - Specify a **`0`** (default) to return a file number in the range **`1 – 255`**, inclusive.
>     - Specify a **`1`** to return a file number in the range **`256 – 511`**.
>
> **`Remarks`**
>
> - Use FreeFile to supply a file number that is not already in use.

Most probably, the reason for **`"Run time error 52"`** ([Bad file name or number (Error 52)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/bad-file-name-or-number-error-52))

---

2. You might be trying to open file **`"anotherFile.txt"`** again, too soon

   There is a way to be more efficient about this logic

---

.

Addressing issue **1.**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcesFiles1()
    Dim fileID As String, txt As String

    'Step 1 of 2 -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    fileID = FreeFile   'Next file number available for use by the Open statement
    Open "D:\Tmp\Test1.txt" For Input As #fileID    'Open file in a Read Mode
    txt = Input(LOF(fileID), #fileID)    'Store file content inside a variable
    Close #fileID                        'Clost Text File

    txt = Replace(txt, "string1", "string2")        'Step 1 of 2

    fileID = FreeFile
    Open "D:\Tmp\Test2.txt" For Output As #fileID   'Open file in Write Mode
    Print #fileID, txt  'Write New Text data to file
    Close #fileID       'Close Text File

    'Step 2 of 2 -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    fileID = FreeFile
    Open "D:\Tmp\Test2.txt" For Input As #fileID    'Open file2 (again) in Read Mode
    txt = Input(LOF(fileID), #fileID)
    Close #fileID

    txt = Replace(txt, "string2", "string3")        'Step 2 of 2

    fileID = FreeFile
    Open "D:\Tmp\Test2.txt" For Output As #fileID   'Open file2 (yet again) in Write Mode
    Print #fileID, txt
    Close #fileID
End Sub
```

---

Risk: Timing issue - `Step 1` conflict with `Step 2`

.

Addressing issue **2.** - Combine `Step 1` and `2` (txt processing independent of files objects)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcesFiles2()
    Dim fileID As String, txt As String

    fileID = FreeFile   'Next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
    Open "D:\Tmp\Test1.txt" For Input As #fileID    'Open file in a Read Mode
    txt = Input(LOF(fileID), #fileID)   'Store file content inside a variable
    Close #fileID                       'Clost Text File

    txt = Replace(txt, "string1", "string2")        'Step 1 of 2
    txt = Replace(txt, "string2", "string3")        'Step 2 of 2

    fileID = FreeFile
    Open "D:\Tmp\Test2.txt" For Output As #fileID   'Open file in Write Mode
    Print #fileID, txt  'Write New Text data to file
    Close #fileID       'Close Text File
End Sub
```